# Why console.log is not called?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning component lifecycle. As I know, getDeafaultProps() is called first when component is creating. I check the log, "Getting our default properties" is not print out. Why?

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {

  getDefaultProps() {
    console.log("Getting our default properties")
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("Before Mounting")
    this.setState({count: 1});
  }


  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>

      <p>
        More info <a href="https://github.com/bradleyboy/codepen-react" target="_blank">here</a>.
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be called since you use ES6 classes. See the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html):

> With functions and ES6 classes defaultProps is defined as a property on the component itself
>
> With `createReactClass()`, you need to define `getDefaultProps()` as a function on the passed object

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `defaultProps` instead of `getDefaultProps`, because you are using `es6`, and you  need to use it like this:

```
static defaultProps = {
    p: console.log("Getting our default properties")
}
```

or define it outside of the `class` in this way:

```
App.defaultProps = {
    p: console.log("Getting our default properties")
}
```

Check this example:

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  
  static defaultProps = {
     p: console.log("Getting our default properties")
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("Before Mounting")
    this.setState({count: 1});
  }


  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>

      <p>
        More info <a href="https://github.com/bradleyboy/codepen-react" target="_blank">here</a>.
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the getDefaultProps method static. It should work.

```
static getDefaultProps() {
    console.log("Getting our default properties")
  }
```